# Inline/Base64 Images in GMail

Tags: html, email

It's quite common for users to paste screenshots from their computer's clipboard into the body of an email but there seems to be problems associated with this.

The main one is that GMail doesn't seem to render the mails (Lotus Notes does) but in some cases shows no image or the actual HTML:
[image]

I've posted the decoded HTML of the mail here: http://cl1p.net/base63emailex and it renders in IE11 and Chrome just fine.

The relevant RAW mail body is available here: https://cl1p.net/base63emailexraw

1) Why does GMail not render the images.
2) Is there a better way of offering users the simple Ctrl+V method of embedding images.

I mean this is 2015 and users of mail clients creating attachments for each image is surely something from the dark ages of computing...

Comment: The pastebins are empty. Also, usually if screenshots are posted into the gmail interface it works.